# userId is null in Firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a post to my Firestore with a few values a get from the app like the title of the post and the content and it worked. But, when I want to get the user Id -who made that post I get **null**.
So How do I fix this? Also, Would I be able to get the user name instead of the id? I think it would be better that way.

Here is the code:

```
onTap: () async {
      if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
        try {
          setState(() {
            _isSubmitting = true;
          });
          FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
            userId = user.uid;
          });
          await Firestore.instance.collection("posts").document().setData({
            'author': userId,
            'title': _titleController.text,
            'body': _bodyController.text,
            'images': "empy for now",
            'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          });
```

Comment: You're supposed to use an auth state observer to get the user data as they sign in or out. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not awaiting the user so the setData function is called before the userId is set to user.uid

thats because .then is asynchronous

to solve this we must wait for the current user to return first

```
    onTap: () async {
  if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isSubmitting = true;
      });
      final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      userId = user.uid;
      await Firestore.instance.collection("posts").document().setData({
        'author': userId,
        'title': _titleController.text,
        'body': _bodyController.text,
        'images': "empy for now",
        'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
```

Comment: yes, that worked thanks a lot, but how can I get the username of the author?

Comment: if by "author" you mean the currentUser, then most probably it would be in the user object returned.
if you mean the author of the posts that you are saving, then it's up to your database schema